# Not able to understand .Net Code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there any idea what he is doing in the below code at line
"`chartSeries.AddItem(new ChartSeriesItem(listData[i].x, listData[i].y));`"

I took this code from one forum.
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/performance-problem-on-line-chart.aspx
I was not able to understand what kind of data holder it is?

Am pulling the data from in dataset format, If I could bind my dataset with listdata, I would acheive this development. But am not undestanding how I need to make this binding.

I have tried as below but didn't worked and throghing an error, please find the attached.

```
Dim listdata As new DataList 
listdata.DataSource = ds.Tables.Item(0)
listdata.DataBind()
```

[image]

**Original code took from forum**

```
ChartSeries chartSeries = new ChartSeries("Altitude", ChartSeriesType.Line); 
chartSeries.Appearance.ShowLabels = false; 
incrementCount = 1; 

for (int i = 0; i < listData.Count; i = i + incrementCount) 
    {
        chartSeries.AddItem(new ChartSeriesItem(listData[i].x, listData[i].y)); 
    }

RadChart2.AddChartSeries(chartSeries);
RadChart2.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "Distance (Miles)"; 
RadChart2.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "Yaxislabel";
```

Comment: Mark correct answers as answers, don't just upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

I think its as simple as this, the error is that you can't use the word `New`, the code from the forum says to use `new`, capitalisation can make all the difference in .NET.

Comment: 1>I have tried without New word, then it is throughing some other errors on each block. on AddItemmethod, ChartseriesItem, Listdata,etc.... 2> I think code at new word area is fine, but just we need to set proper data in "listdata", If understand what kind of dataholder is this, then we might close this.